# Node js/Express to replace LAMP

Tags: php, node.js, apache, express, xampp

I need help from you NodeJS ninjas. I am starting to learn it, after doing a good amount of LAMP stuff. I have written several systems in Apache/PHP/MySQL for a small corporate intranet (including things like a ticket system, employee scheduling, production reports, financial reports, etc).

So, in LAMP world, I start the Apache and MySQL engine. Then people go to their browsers, type the server IP and browse the different systems I've written for them based on the folder in htdocs.

I am trying to think what the equivalent would be in a set up with NodeJS, Express using the MVC model (something I am also new to). Two main questions:

1. Since I have several systems (employee scheduling, financial
   reports, etc), would each one of these have their own middleware for managing, with their middleware rules and all that? or would they all run under just a main thread? (load balancing is another thing that came up).
2. What would the folder layout be? XAMPP had the htdocs folder and the folder structure was whatever I wanted.

From what I've seen in most tutorials, an option for a folder layout is:

-app
-- controllers
-- models
-- routes
-- views
-config
-- env
-node_modules
-public (I imagine the systems I implement would be on here?)
-server.js

Thank you for your help, I am still a complete noob, but I am excited to get into this.

Comment: The folder structure can be whatever you want in a node project as well. You might be best off using a opinionated framework though - one that has made most of these decisions for you. I'd suggest SailsJS, but there's been some disagreements in the project - leading to some devs starting off from fresh with TrailsJS. You can find some node framework suggestions here: http://designpixy.com/2015/node-js-frameworks-2015/

Comment: Search for information about *routing*.  Glance at SLIM (PHP) (which I think borrows from Sinatra (Ruby)), before stepping over.

Answer (score 1):

I come from LAMP stack word and moved to nodeJS 2 years ago. A lot changed since then.

Things you need to know for nodeJS vs PHP :

- nodeJS runs under google's JavaScript V8 engine.
- nodeJS is ingle-threaded.  PHP is multi-thread. That means any modification to a global variable, if there's any, is seen by all the connected users.
- nodeJS with express alone is not MVC since MVC is a architectural pattern.  You can if you want create folders to define a MVC pattern or hMVC pattern (depending on your needs).  A bigger frameworks called SAILS does native MVC for you.
- to start a nodeJS project, you have to cli node yourApp.js.  That said, there is a better way to start a project using a script placed inside package.json managed by npm or using other npm package such as nodemon.  There is no specific folder to start a project like PHP since PHP is managed by Apache and Apache is configured to have a specific folder for html docs.
- Other things to add :
- Javascript uses EcmaScript as scripting language.  The version 6 of ES was finalised in summer 2015, and all browsers still doesn't native take it in charge.  Since nodejs uses google's v8 engine, it's still based on ES5.1 or experimental ES6 with --hamrony flag calling node in cli.  Since node5 many ES6 features are implemented but still not all are.
- NodeJS is asynchronous, and async call are HARD to learn when you come from php word.  You will need a lot of practices.  I suggest you go read module pattern and revealing pattern.

I hope I have answered you'r questions